# Is there any option to add file upload/attachment field in webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

Is there any option to add file upload/attachment field in webform for Drupal 8?

My webform version is 8.x-5.0-beta7+20-dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will need to define the private file system to get the web form upload fields. By default the private file system was not defined that's why the upload fields were not showing up. After defining the private file system through the settings.php file and clearing the cache I found several upload fields option to add in the form.

Comment: Please see https://www.drupal.org/psa-2016-003 for more information about why the webform module is now strongly encouraging everyone to use private file uploads.